# Automatically keep track of all changes to a folder

Tags: version-control

Is there any software for Ubuntu that can keep track of changes to a specific folder, and restore previous versions of the folder? It would be useful to see all the changes that had been made to a specific folder (so that if I modified a file by accident, I could quickly restore the file to its original state.)

Comment: cvs perhaps? I haven't tried it myself but I thought I'd suggest it anyway since I know of people who do use it.

Comment: Also, it looks like it might be possible to do this (at least for one specific file) using Git: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420143/making-git-auto-commit

Answer (score 2):

Okay, for some reason I don't have the "comment" option to post this but note that this isn't an answer. I'm assuming you are asking if there is something similar to the "Previous Versions" option in Windows Vista and Windows 7 in Ubuntu? If so, I have not found anything native to Ubuntu. What I have done to mimic this behavior is install Dropbox and sync the folders I wish to have previous versions of and then restore the previous versions through their interface. It's a hackjob but it works for what I need it to.

Comment: Does Dropbox keep track of a folder's revision history, or are you using another program to do this?

Comment: Yes but you have to go through their website to view the previous versions. When you want to see the previous versions available you can right click on the file and select "Previous Versions" from the context menu. This will take you to a list of available versions for a file as well as the date and time the revision was made.

Comment: Also, are there any versioning file systems for Ubuntu that can keep track of changes to the file system?

Comment: What you are looking for is an OS feature, not a file system. You could try installing a SVN or CVS but that is geared at programmers in a distributed development environment... I think this will help you better understand the types of file systems under Linux:

http://www.basicconfig.com/linux-basics/filesystem-types

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, versioning file systems are supposed to keep track of changes to files. Why would it be better to use an "OS feature" than to use a versioning file system?

Comment: I don't see any mention of versioning file systems for Linux on that page - are they discussed elsewhere?

Comment: You're thinking of a Journaling File System which is something completely different. Version control is a programmatic idea.